# Google Calendar api - rate limit exceeded (even though it's not)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an App Engine app that works with various Google APIs. I started a sync task that syncs like 3000 events to various users calendars. It worked for a while but now I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

If I look into the Api Dashboard, the limit is really high:

Queries per day 1,000,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user    50,000,000.

How can I get over this error? I want this task to finish so users see the events in their calendar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rate Limit Exceeded Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868737/rate-limit-exceeded-google-calendar)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) user rate limit is flood protection.  An application can only make X number of requests per second.

> 403: Rate Limit Exceeded
>   The per-user limit from the Developer Console has been reached.

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

Suggested actions:

Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).

You can try adding quota user this helps sometimes.

> quotaUser  An arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user.
>   Lets you enforce per-user quotas from a server-side application even in cases when the user's IP address is unknown. This can occur, for example, with applications that run cron jobs on App Engine on a user's behalf.
>   You can choose any arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user, but it is limited to 40 characters.

If you are getting a quota error then it has been exceeded even though you dont think it has. Application level quotas can not be increased.  The only thing you can do is slow down.

Comment: as you can see, the error i get is not userRateLimitExceeded but rateLimitExceeded. It's completely different. You answer is not helping at all. I raised the limits too.

Comment: Its the application level quota then which means there is nothing you can do besides implement backoff and slow down.   It used to be documented what the application level quotas were if memory serves its around 10 per second or 100 per 100 seconds.    They appear to have removed it from the documentation which problem means its changed.

Comment: How can "Queries per 100 seconds per user" be higher than "Queries per day"

Comment: you can use your per day quota in an hour if you want google isnt going to care when you use up your Queries per day.  Its up to you as the developer to either apply for a quota extension or spread out your request thought out the day so you dont run out.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an answer to this question either. The default is 500 requests per 100 seconds, and even if I increased it, after some time, I can only make 5 requests/second which matches with a limit of 500.

That means the old default is always being used.