# Rate Limit Exceeded Google Calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

We are using Google Cloud instances (AppEngine) to synchronize data for our users with their Google Calendars (through the Calendar API). Basically, we provide a task management solution and the tasks should be synchronized (unidirectional) with the calendars they (the users) provide us access for.

How it all works:
1. We ask the users to grant access to their Google Account.
2. We ask them to select the desired calendar or offer the possibility of creating a new one under their account.
3. We push inserts/updates/deletes through the API.

The specific error we don't understand is 403 "Rate Limit Exceeded", which we received 190 times in the last 30 days from a total of 84,773 requests.

```
"error": {
 "errors": [
 {
 "domain": "usageLimits",
 "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
 "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
 ],
"code": 403,
"message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}
}
```

The reason we don't understand is because the maximum number of queries/day we have made is around 8K. The maximum daily limit we have in the Google Cloud API setting is 1 million.

Are there any other limits we need to be aware of? If not, what could be causing the issue? Did anyone face a similar scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [rate limit error](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) is not the same as the daily usage limit error. The rate limit is a safety limit to ensure we are not bombarded with requests over a short period of time.

You can use exponential backoff retry algorithms to ensure rate limit doesn't stop your app dead in the water (instead it just slows it down).

Comment: Thank you! We will implement exponential backoff and let you know the outcome.

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know how that goes for you :)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, without a logic reason, and we have solved it by using the [batch mode](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md)