# Google Calendar API: IP address tracing and quota prices

Tags: ip, google-calendar-api, ip-address, price, quota

In our ERP system [Qi](http://www.qi.cz/), which has about 1200 customers, we use the Google Calendar API. In the Google developer console, I found that about a month ago the number of requests jumped from 150,000 to 700,000 per day. As a result, about 40 percent of requests now return a rateLimitExceeded error (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868737/rate-limit-exceeded-google-calendar)).

I have questions:

- How can I find out who caused the load increase (IP address, login, etc.)?
- What is Google's pricing policy about quotes? How much would it cost to increase the quota from eg 1 million to 10 million?

Thank you.
Regards, Petr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only for G Suite users:**

You can check which users made API Requests in the Audit tool of your Google Admin Console. Go to [Reports > Audit > Calendar](https://admin.google.com/ac/reporting/audit/calendar) and filter by `API Kind > Calendar API`.

Regarding the Quotas, you can upgrade them in your [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) by clicking on Upgrade Account.

Comment: Thank you. I tried log in to the Google Admin Console, but i received this error: "admin.google.com is used for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com." Does this mean that my account is not designed for such use and I need to create a new G Suite account? If I create this account, will the current project (identified by Client ID and Client secret) work? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need a G Suite account, but you can't use your gmail one, as it will create a @domain-name.com email account. So you would have to create a new Client Id and Secret. In this case, I would say you cannot Audit these requests. You could do it for future requests if you were using a G Suite account.

Comment: Thank you, @Jescanellas, I understand. Do you know where I can find out the prices for increasing the quota? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you can go to this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247360?hl=en). I edited my answer so I would be thankful if you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so others know it's correct. Cheers!