# Google Calendar API returns a rate limit exceeded error during batch processing

Tags: google-calendar-api, limit

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60988677) ... I changed the Google Calendar API call to [batch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch), but some requests in the batch return a 403 - [rateLimitExceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868737/) "Rate Limit Exceeded" error. There is always a maximum of 50 requests of the same type in the batch, most often PATCH. But errors occur even if the batch contains less than 10 requests. On average, only about 50% of all requests are successful.

Example request (part with one reguest):

```
--googlebatch_20200513_171515_647
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item:0>

PATCH /calendar/v3/calendars/XXX/YYY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 449

{
  "summary": "Opakovaná aktivita 2",
  "description": "",
  "id": "XXX",
  "start": { "dateTime": "2020-05-07T09:00:00+02:00" },
  "end": { "dateTime": "2020-05-07T09:30:00+02:00" },
  "location": "", 
  "visibility": "default", 
  "reminders": {"useDefault": false},
  "transparency": "opaque", 
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "X-QIID": "29037717,10",
      "X-QISyncOn": "1"
    }
  }
}
...
next requests
... 
--googlebatch_20200513_171515_647--
```

Example response:

```
--batch_preSx1sqdvk_AAP51GVWcoo
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-item:0>

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 13 May 2020 15:15:16 GMT
Expires: Mon, 13 May 2020 15:15:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 199

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
--batch_preSx1sqdvk_AAP51GVWcoo--
```

I don't understand why the Google API returns this error, because when I send a batch request, I just send the batch and the execution of individual requests is controlled by Google itself. So I have no way to influence the speed of their launch. If batch execution is too fast, why doesn't Google slow it down and complete all requests successfully?

What else could I do? Where could be the mistake? What do you recommend me?

Thank you. Regards, Petr.

Comment: Are you using a service account? Please provide you relevant code.

Comment: Please remove this confidential information, I just asked because I think your problem is related to using a service account. Can you provide you your code or the methods you are using? E.g., do you create an event with invitees?

Comment: Thank you. OK, I removed previous comment. Yes, I use service account. I use [TMS VCL Cloud Pack](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/cloudpack.asp) for Delphi. HTTPS methods POST, PATCH and DELETE are used there. I create events without invitees. An example of a typical event is given in my post. The problem is, that some of requests within the batch were carried out successfully and some not.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. If you are not exceeding your quota, the error is most likely originating from using a service account and can be avoided by either using impersonation and not using a service account at all. You suggest you test it to confirm if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

### There are  [known issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761425) with the Calendar API throwing 403 error sooner than expected when using a service account

The workaround would be using [impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#impersonating_a_service_account), that is to make the service-account act on behalf of a user. This allows to avoid the 403 errors.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object) for code samples.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm not sure if my previous answer was correct. I'll try to clarify. In our application we use login to "Native client 1" via "Client ID" and "Client secret", users authorize services via "OAuth consent screen" and get a refresh token. And from the refresh token, an access token is then obtained, which is used to make requests. So I think the requests sent from our application are personalized and are not affected by this issue.

Comment: If you are not using  a service account it is different. But then the question is how many simultaneous batch requests do you make? Also, is there any pattern which requests give you 403 and which don't?

Comment: Currently, production applications for customers run in the mode of individual requirements. I only tested the batch processing on my own, so only one batch was running at a time. Each batch contained a maximum of 50 requests. The individual batch requests were similar to the above, differing only in the property values. Almost the same request in a batch passes once and does not pass another time. Example of a complete [request](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OJ0WuptRO3kYbdeYXZT1UKSphSWxSOXX) and [response](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TIgc0bvwzTDcpRJolV9w3_g8wkbhGd6q).

Comment: The limits are usually `Queries per 100 seconds per user 500`, if you are sure that you make less requests than this per 100 s, it is hard to explain your error - unless you ar eusing a service account for testing. If you are a GSuite customer, you are entitled to [support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en). If you are sure you do not hit the quota and do not use a service account, I recommend you to consult it with GSuite support, since your problem is likely to be related to your specific account.

Comment: @PetrKolar

Having the exact same issue as you. Calendar requests sent to the batch endpoint. with accesstoken. Less than 50 per request, but nearly all returned as 403 rateLimitExceeded.

Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: RateLimit exceeded is a common issue with batch requests, the best solution is to incorporate exponential back off logarithms.